# I want to block my transaction

Tags: revert-transaction

I made a payment to somebody and now he is not replying me regarding the product I made the payment for and think its a fraud.
So I want to block the transaction.
All I have is the QR code of the person to whom the payment was made.
I also have the QR code detail
Bitcoin:1PNPnadF26twbAxTZTVeEaQKjbYeXDmeNJ

Comment: Sorry, that's not how it works.  When you pay with bitcoin, you are essentially paying cash.  Since you have the recipient's address, you can look up the transaction on a block explorer like http://blockchain.info, but my guess is is that your transaction already has a few confirmations.  You can ask for your money back, but that's it.

Comment: Can you help block the address because i am unable to do anything about it.

Comment: No.  That's not how Bitcoin works.  I have no more power to do this than you do.  Looking at that address (https://blockchain.info/address/1PNPnadF26twbAxTZTVeEaQKjbYeXDmeNJ?filter=2), I can see that there are many transactions to the address.  I can also see that all the transactions to that address are confirmed by more than 6 blocks.  I don't know which is yours, but it is irreversable.  In fact, I can see that all outputs to that address are already spent.  Talk to the recipient, because all that can be done is convincing them to send your money back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they are asking for help doing the impossible.  They have not adequately researched their problem, and are treating this forum like a customer service department for Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction has been confirmed there is nothing to do and that is probably your situation. If not (due a small fee) then you can pay yourself with a higher fee to "block" the previous one.